# What are the precautions to take when building circuits powered over USB from a Laptop?

Tags: pcb-design, avr, usb-device

I am working on a rather simple embedded system project which involves an hardware USB enabled AVR chip communicating with a host of other devices and a solid state relay which is used to make or break a 110V AC circuit . This AVR is powered over USB from a laptop . What are the precautions to keep in mind to prevent it from frying my laptop's USB port .Would a simple fuse in VBUS solve the issue?

Comment: Noise decoupling is critical from both conducted and radiated.  Noise levels are unknown from your description.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I haven't yet built a circuit , was just deciding on which AVR to use . As a result , I don't  have all the details presently.

Comment: Its wise to use opto isolated ZCS Triac drivers. But when I did it 40 yrs ago, I wound my own pulse transformer and used AC divider to make ZCS pulses. Now you can buy these in SMT and get 3kV galvanic isolation.  But EMI experience you need.

Comment: Fuses protect wires from catching on fire. They are almost never fast enough to protect silicon. Also, fuses trip based on sustained over-current. They don't trip due to voltage. The main thing you need to do is isolate the mains voltage from the rest of the circuit. In some PCB's (e.g., charger) I have seen actual airgaps carved out of the PCB to provide airgap isolation between mains voltage and low voltage.

Comment: From a system level design perspective, you also have to make sure the mains voltage wires are in a separate partition of your device, so that accidental contact during installation is unlikely. You may want to take a look at how thermostats are designed. Just go to a hardware store and look one over without buying it. I mean the type of thermostat that operates a mains voltage heater, for example.